# Uncaught OAuthException: thrown in posting scores

Tags: facebook, api, exception, oauth

I'm trying to post a **test account user's** score from a **test facebook application** using the graph ***"/me/scores"*** with an acquired ***app token***. However, in trying to do so I get

> Uncaught OAuthException: An unexpected error has occurred. Please
>   retry your request later. thrown in base_facebook.php on line 1039

the code is simple

```
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
        "client_id=" . APP_ID .
        "&client_secret=" . APP_SECRET .
        "&grant_type=client_credentials";
$app_access_token = split('=',file_get_contents($token_url));
$response = $facebook->api(  
                 '/'.$me['id'].'/scores',  
                 'post',  
                    array(  
                     'score' => 1, 
                     'access_token' => $app_access_token[1]
                        )  
                    ); 

echo $response;
$data = $facebook->api('/me/scores'); $me['score'] = $data['data']; 
print_r($me);
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: It may seem like the problem is the test user account...I was able to post a score using my account but a test user account give me this error....How am I suppose to build a game in test mode when I can't test it out on test user accounts.... :-/